# Getting the % Difference of two columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am selecting a count for a column based on a given month/year. I need to return the difference in a percentage of that count compared to last months.

Here's what I have thus far. This returns the first half of what I need (the current month count).

```
select 
    o.productName, COUNT(*) as totalSales 
from 
    order o
inner join 
    product p on o.productID=p.productID
where 
    datePart(month, dateTimeReceived) = 2
    and datePart(year, dateTimeReceived) = 2012         
group by 
    o.productName
order by 
    totalSales desc
```

So the output of this appears as follows

```
Widget 1  - 200 sold
Widget 2  - 190 sold
```

Again, I would also like to include a 3rd column which captures % change from the previous month.

Also, I am not getting a warm fuzzy with regards to how I am selecting with `datePart` so if you have a recommendation on how to approach that better I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED: Didn't read the bit about the percentage column. This returns 4 columns, productName, currentMonth, previousMonth and percentChange. The ISNULL function is there to prevent "divide by zero" errors. You could adapt this into a proc and just pass in the CurrentYear & CurrentMonth parameters, or you could pass in a single datetime parameter and let it work out the month/year from that, or even use GETDATE() and not pass any parameters.

```
declare @CurrentYear int,
    @CurrentMonth int,
    @previousYear int,
    @previousMonth int

set @CurrentYear = 2012
set @CurrentMonth = 2

if @CurrentMonth = 1 begin
    set @previousMonth = 12
    set @previousYear = @CurrentYear - 1
end else begin
    set @previousMonth = @CurrentMonth - 1
    set @previousYear = @CurrentYear
end

select  productName,
    (select COUNT(*) 
    from    [order] o 
    where   DATEPART(year, dateTimeReceived) = @CurrentYear
    and DATEPART(month, dateTimeReceived) = @CurrentMonth
    and o.productid = p.productid) as currentMonth,
    (select COUNT(*) 
    from    [order] o 
    where   DATEPART(year, dateTimeReceived) = @previousYear
    and DATEPART(month, dateTimeReceived) = @previousMonth
    and o.productid = p.productid) as previousMonth,
    convert(decimal(10, 2), 100*(
    (select COUNT(*) 
    from    [order] o 
    where   DATEPART(year, dateTimeReceived) = @CurrentYear
    and DATEPART(month, dateTimeReceived) = @CurrentMonth
    and o.productid = p.productid) 
    -
    (select COUNT(*) 
    from    [order] o 
    where   DATEPART(year, dateTimeReceived) = @previousYear
    and DATEPART(month, dateTimeReceived) = @previousMonth
    and o.productid = p.productid)
    /
    NULLIF(
    (select COUNT(*) 
    from    [order] o 
    where   DATEPART(year, dateTimeReceived) = @previousYear
    and DATEPART(month, dateTimeReceived) = @previousMonth
    and o.productid = p.productid), 0))) as percentChange
from    product p
```

Comment: Sean, thanks! Just FYI, the forumula should be convert(decimal(10,2),100*(old-new) / old) as foo. You had a paren in the wrong place slightly, but you were 99.9% correct, so I am marking this as the answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Good use of NULLIF, but inline views on the select clause are notorious bad performers and completely unnecessary in this case. Also this will include all products even if they're not ordered. Not sure if that's good or bad for the OP.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways to produce the result you want. This one uses a CTE to calculate the totals for both months and then joins it back to itself.

```
With cte as 
(
SELECT 

       o.productname, 
       Datepart(month, datetimereceived) m,
       Count(*) AS totalSales 
FROM   order o 
       INNER JOIN product p 
               ON o.productid = p.productid 
WHERE  Datepart(month, datetimereceived) in ( 2, 2-1) 
       AND Datepart(year, datetimereceived) = 2012 
GROUP  BY o.productname, 
       Datepart(month, datetimereceived) 
ORDER  BY totalsales DESC )
SELECT 
      a.productName ,
      a.totalSales,
      a.totalSales / b.totalSales percentage_of_prevous_month

FROM 
      cte a 
      INNER JOIN cte b 
      ON a.productname = b.productname
         and a.month = b.month - 1
```

There are some pieces missing. You'll probably actually need to do something like to get a non zero value, if the division results in a number < 0

```
cast(a.totalSales as decimal)/ cast( b.totalSales  as decimal)
```

Also the using the Month input like this will cause problems if your input is January. So you're better of normalizing the datetimerecived to the first of the month

e.g.

Modified SELECT and Group by

```
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(@mydate)-1),datetimerecieved),101) m
```

Modified WHERE

```
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(datetimerecieved)-1),datetimerecieved),101)
                  in ( '2/1/2012', DateAdd(m,-1,'2/1/2012'))
```

Modified ON

```
a.M > b.M
```

Comment: Thanks conrad, how do we address the year if the month is January?